# How to compute aggregates like in relational databases

Tags: c++

Say I have a data set like this:

```
MONTH   REGION  SALES
NOV_2011    North   15000
NOV_2011    North   15000
OCT_2010    West    14000
NOV_2011    North   15000
OCT_2010    West    14000
OCT_2010    West    7000
APR_2010    North   3000
DEC_2011    South   24000
APR_2010    North   9000
```

I want to get a sum of sales by month and region.

```
MONTH   REGION  SALES
APR_2010    North   12000
DEC_2011    South   24000
NOV_2011    North   45000
OCT_2010    West    35000
```

If this data was in a relational table I can easily write a sql to get the answer. All databases can give an answer almost instantaneously ( of course depending on volume, indexes etc).
I would like to use C++ facilities to do this kind of computation because sometimes the task is not worth adding a sql library.
Are there data structures algorithms out there that can make such tasks easier?

Comment: look at a `map` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/. You can store the Month & Region as a key and the Sales as the value. You would have to parse through all the data and add it to the `map`.

Comment: @twain249 That is what I normally do in situations like this but think about a situation where you have 15 or more columns? The key can become quite huge

Comment: You should reorganize your data according to the database rules so that tables have minimal duplicate entries.

Comment: @user841550 if you create a class that holds all the information and use that as the key they will be unique based on the comparator methods you define.

Answer (score 0):

You can build index tables for keys in a column using a `std::map`.

One issue is that your data contains duplicate rows.  For example, where month == NOV_2011 and region == North and Sales == 15000.  This makes using an `std::map` impractical, as you would have to have the Value as a list or other container (one key item, a container of row indices for each key entry).

Most database designers make access faster by redesigning the data in the table.  Search for "relational database normalization".

Comment: Yes, the "table" in my example is not normalized. But any relational database would have no difficulty resolving my query such as 'select month, region, sum(sales) as sales from T group by month, region'